# Why i'm getting undefined using Boolean object?

Tags: javascript

```
function boo(arr)
{
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
 { 
   var bob = new Boolean(arr[i]);
   if(bob === false)
    {

     console.log(arr[i]);   

    }

 }
}
console.log(boo([0,"how",89,false]));
```

I want to check all the false values like false,null,undefined etc.from an array using Boolean Object and print it. How can i do it using Boolean Object?. How can i add multiple values for checking whether it is `true` or `false` in Boolean Object?

Comment: You have to use `!!` operator

Comment: @Legends: There is no such thing. That is the `!` operator, applied twice.

Comment: of course........

Comment: *bob* is an object, objects are only ever `===` to themselves. Perhaps you want `var bob = Boolean(arr[i])`, i.e. remove *new* so you get a primitive, not an object.

Comment: @RobG Thanks even it did work

Answer (score 2):

You can't compare `Boolean` objects that way in javascript. `new Boolean(...) === false` will always evaluate to `false`.

[MDN has a good warning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean) on the matter:

> Do not confuse the primitive Boolean values true and false with the true and false values of the Boolean object.

For instance (given `value = arr[i]`), if you need to see if something is truthy just use `!!value`. For falsey, use `!value`. If you need to see if something is really `true` use `value === true`, likewise for `false`, but not a `Boolean` instance.

Comment: Might want to clarify that `value` here is `arr[i]`, not `bob`.

Comment: Thanks it worked :)Can you tell me when do we use ! and !! i never used it before and don't know much about it.

Comment: @caycospete `!` is the NOT operator which takes any falsey value and makes it `true` (and any truthy value and makes it `false`). `!!` is just 2 `!` and it flips the value, effectively casting the value to a boolean.

Comment: You could use == instead of === and it would work, although this wouldn't be advisable and could lead to confusion